# Is there a Possibility to call One app1 (view) into another app2(view) in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am confused that can we call one App view to Another app view in sencha touch 2

Comment: Can u be more specific? call one app into other? What r u trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "can you load a second sencha app, into a view (or container) of the original Sencha app" then the answer is YES.

I had to do this before Sencha Touch Charts 2 was released. I was creating a second app in ST1 with Charts 1, and then loading that inside my ST2 application view.

For that, you will need to use iFrames to call the second app to load inside yours. There is NO OTHER WAY. I tried everything. Also, if you want to pass data from one app to another, use the localstorage or SQLlite database calls.